# Docky in ubuntu how to customize

Tags: 14.04, docky

[Those weird things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wBzx.png) (I don't know what it is called) appeared after installing docky. But they are useless. How can i make them vanish? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed an application called cairo-dock, which is similar to docky but does not contain those weird issues, so problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the GUI.
you can't have the exact same graphics.

What's your graphics card?
By default Ubuntu use the open source video driver Nouveau for NVIDIA graphics card. This driver lacks support for 3D acceleration and may not work with the very latest video cards or technologies from NVIDIA. An alternative to Nouveau are the closed source unified NVIDIA drivers, which are developed by NVIDIA. This driver provides excellent 3D acceleration and video card support.

Comment: okay, but how can i remove them?

Comment: i added more answer

Comment: Though, my machine working well now.  I have NVIDIA, with 2 gb ram. But i don't think it is related with this. Because it is just a view, functioning may not  be the same.

Comment: just right clicked to those things. They are there because of the application called docky, and i edit the question accordingly.